# when A and B are independent?

Tags: probability

There are $n$ children in a family $P(boy)=P(girl)=1/2$.

$A$ = “The family has children of both genders”.

$B$ = “There is at most one girl in the family”.

For which values of $n$ the events $A$ and $B $ are independent?

Comment: Ddi you try to apply the definition?

Comment: When does $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$?

Comment: To get started, pick some small values for $n$, say $n≤4$ and see how it goes.